# Pylint ignore rules on git action

Tags: python, pylint

I've used the default pylint from `git actions` to check my project for any errors.

There are some errors that I want to ignore though. If it was in vscode you could ignore them in `settings.json`. How do I ignore them in `git actions`?

```
name: Pylint

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: ["3.10"]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install pylint
    - name: Analysing the code with pylint
      run: |
        pylint $(git ls-files '*.py')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. you could use [noqa](https://www.alpharithms.com/noqa-python-501210/) comments for ignore specific lines
2. you can run probably pylint with option disable or something like that:

```
pylint -d C0114,C0116 $(git ls-files '*.py')
```

this would disable warnings with the codes `C0114` and `C0116`

Comment: noqa won't work with pylint : https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/messages/message_control.html here's the doc for the -d option https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/configuration/all-options.html#disable